# How to create a new ASP.NET MVC web-site in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

From [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) i downloaded the [MVC 3 Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215693), and ran it:

[image]

When it finished, i loaded Visual Studio and *tried* to create a "New" Web-site. But there's no option to create an ASP.NET MVC web-site:

[image]

i expected to see something *like* what's shown on the ASP.NET MVC homepage:

[image]

---

There is also a [Getting Started tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) that lists the steps to follow:

> ### Creating Your First Application
>
> You can create applications using either Visual Basic or Visual C# as
>   the programming language. Select Visual C# on the left and then select
>   **ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application**.
>
> [image]

---

After that didn't work, i also tried:

- [image] [a web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=VWDorVS2010SP1Pack)
- [image] [another Web Platform Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208140) (from [the MVC3 homepage](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3))
- or download the [installer here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3) (also from [the MVC3 homepage](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on File -> New PROJECT (NOT WEBSITE). it should be in your list

Answer (score 1):

Look in your control panel
DO you have -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on New Project and Under Visual C#, select the Web Menu Item. In the list of projects you should see a ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application. Thats what you need to use.

Btw - Are you using Visual Studio Express??